# Что лучше для связанных boolean, проверка или присвоение сразу?

Tags: java, c, оптимизация, компилятор

Интересует вопрос, что оптимальнее для bool операции:

```
if (var1) var2 = false
else var2 = true
```

или

```
var2 = !var1
```

Другими словами - оптимальнее сравнивать и при условии присваивать нужное значение или проще сразу присваивать отрицание?

Comment: Конечно же второй вариант. Первый мало того что медленный, ещё и запутанный.

Comment: Вы реально заботитесь об оптимизации в одну наносекунду? Вангую, что оптимизирующий компилятор сгенерирует строго одинаковый код.

Comment: Если в каком-либо компиляторе первый вариант будет оптимальнее второго - это хороший повод задуматься о качестве исполнения этого компилятора.

Comment: @VladD Так и есть - см. мой ответ, в особенности для Open Watcom :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я пишу для микропроцессора - вот и возникла мысль, что второй вариант гораздо быстрее, просто я ассемблера не знаю.

Всё зависит от компилятора. Он может инлайнить эту функцию в место вызова и делать с ней что угодно в зависимости от окружающего кода. Вообще, я бы ожидал, что получится одинаковый код, хотя это может быть и не так.

Можно вспомнить, что в си любое нелулевое значение является истинным, поэтому само по себе инвертирование просто так не сделать. Насколько я понимаю, оно должно разложиться в инструкцию `test` и условный переход.

Варианты, как я бы мог написать такое на ассемблере (примерно, на уровне идей). Специально не использую ret, предполагая, что функция будет инлайниться.

1. Самый примитивный вариант, похож на первый код безо всяких оптимизаций:

   ```
   test a
   jz ZERO
   jmp NONZERO
   ZERO: mov b 1
   jmp DONE
   NONZERO: mov b 0
   DONE: no
   ```

   Проверка, условный переход, присваивание, безусловный переход (не всегда).
2. Похож на первый, немного оптимизированный:

   ```
   test a
   jz ZERO
   mov b 0
   jmp DONE
   ZERO: mov b 1
   DONE: nop
   ```

   Проверка, присваивание, ровно 1 переход (но в одном из двух мест).
3. `b = 0; if (!a) b = 1;` оптимизированный:

   ```
   xor b, b // то же, что `mov b 0`, но быстрее
   test a
   jnz NONZERO
   mov b 1
   NONZERO: nop
   ```

   Для истинного `a`: Присваивание, проверка, переход.
   Для ложного `a`: Присваивание, проверка, присваивание.

**Думаю, для варианта `b = !a` компилятор сам выберет оптимальный вариант. Это весьма простая конструкция, с которой ему должно быть проще разобраться, поэтому стоит выбирать её. Да и вообще, она читаемее.**

4. Да, и ещё фишка. Если компилятор уверен, что там 0 или 1, он может заменить инвертирование на `xor` вот так `b = a ^ 1`:

   ```
   mov b a
   xor b 1
   ```

   Одно перемещение и одна битовая операция.

PS: А ещё он может воспользоваться специфическими командами, которые я не знаю или не вспомнил. Или которые есть только в конкретном процессоре.

Comment: Вариант 4 хорош. В x86 есть команда `sete` (узнал благодаря этому вопросу и gcc -S) -- "Sets the byte in the operand to 1 if the Zero Flag is set,
        otherwise sets the operand to 0." / gcc -O3 использует как раз ее после testl

Comment: Вообще без переходов :) `mov ebx, [var2] // xor eax, eax //  sub ebx, 1 // adc eax, 0 // mov [var1], eax` Правда, длинновато и бесполезно с учётом других вариантов.

Comment: Именно про 4 вариант я и думал, когда задавал вопрос. Но судя по комментариям, получается,  что эта операция обрабатывается в силу возможностей компилятора и как правило в результате получается либо одинаковое число шагов, либо более оптимально во втором случае. Что ж, спасибо за комментарии)

Answer (score 4):

@Uraty неплохо расписал, я попробую зайти с другой стороны.

Написал два небольших метода.

```
private static boolean m1(boolean value) {
    boolean result;
    if (value) result = false;
    else result = true;

    return result;
}

private static boolean m2(boolean value) {
    boolean result = !value;
    return result;
}
```

Скомпилировал и посмотрел байткод:

```
private static boolean m1(boolean);
     0: iload_0
     1: ifeq          9
     4: iconst_0
     5: istore_1
     6: goto          11
     9: iconst_1
     10: istore_1
     11: iload_1
     12: ireturn

private static boolean m2(boolean);
     0: iload_0      
     1: ifne         
     4: iconst_1     
     5: goto          9
     8: iconst_0
     9: istore_1
    10: iload_1
    11: ireturn
```

Понимать все не обязательно, стоит лишь заметить, что в обоих методах получалось *почти* одинаковое число инструкций, и они почти идентичны, за исключением одной инструкции:  в методе `m1()` присутствует `ifeq` в `m2()` `ifen` - проверка на равенство и проверка на неравенство.

Можно сделать вывод, что они идентичны, но запись вида:

```
boolean result = !value
```

выглядит более лаконичней.

Comment: _"в обоих методах получалось одинаковое число инструкций"_ - эм.. во втором же больше? 8 vs 9.

Comment: ах, ну да, вы правы)

Comment: это байт код жавы? то есть, она обычное отрицание булевой переменной развернула в целый if-goto?

Comment: @KoVadim ага, так и есть

Answer (score 4):

На С++ оптимизируется [одинаково](https://godbolt.org/g/UWViMg):

```
bool f(bool var1)
{
  bool var2 = !var1;
  return var2;
}

bool g(bool var1)
{
  bool var2;
  if (var1) var2 = false;
  else var2 = true;
  return var2;
}
```

превращаются в одно и то же:

```
f(bool):
        mov     eax, edi
        xor     eax, 1
        ret
g(bool):
        mov     eax, edi
        xor     eax, 1
        ret
```

**Update**
Да, это в самом деле С++, каюсь. Ну, возьмем VC++ 2015.
В режиме C++ c оптимизацией код одинаков:

```
g:
    cmp BYTE PTR _var1$[esp-4], 0
    sete    al
f:
    cmp BYTE PTR _var1$[esp-4], 0
    sete    al
```

Без оптимизации все страшно ;)

```
g:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _var1$[ebp]
    test    eax, eax
    je  SHORT $LN2@g
    mov BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN3@g
$LN2@g:
    mov BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp], 1
$LN3@g:
    mov al, BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0

f:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _var1$[ebp]
    test    eax, eax
    jne SHORT $LN3@f
    mov DWORD PTR tv66[ebp], 1
    jmp SHORT $LN4@f
$LN3@f:
    mov DWORD PTR tv66[ebp], 0
$LN4@f:
    mov cl, BYTE PTR tv66[ebp]
    mov BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp], cl
    mov al, BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
```

Т.е. длинно, но **практически** одинаково.

Для С код чуть подправлен:

```
#define  bool _Bool

bool f(bool var1)
{
  bool var2 = !var1;
  return var2;
}

bool g(bool var1)
{
  bool var2;
  if (var1) var2 = 0;
  else var2 = 1;
  return var2;
}
```

Получаем с оптимизацией *точно то же, что и для C++*:

```
_g  PROC                        ; COMDAT
    cmp BYTE PTR _var1$[esp-4], 0
    sete    al
    ret 0
_g  ENDP

_f  PROC                        ; COMDAT
    cmp BYTE PTR _var1$[esp-4], 0
    sete    al
    ret 0
_f  ENDP
```

И без оптимизации:

```
_g  PROC
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push    ecx
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _var1$[ebp]
    test    eax, eax
    je  SHORT $LN2@g
    mov BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp], 0
    jmp SHORT $LN3@g
$LN2@g:
    mov BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp], 1
$LN3@g:
    mov al, BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_g  ENDP

_f  PROC
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 8
    movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _var1$[ebp]
    test    eax, eax
    jne SHORT $LN3@f
    mov DWORD PTR tv66[ebp], 1
    jmp SHORT $LN4@f
$LN3@f:
    mov DWORD PTR tv66[ebp], 0
$LN4@f:
    mov cl, BYTE PTR tv66[ebp]
    mov BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp], cl
    mov al, BYTE PTR _var2$[ebp]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_f  ENDP
```

Опять же, разница есть, но очень невелика..

Если соптимизировать сами функции, объявив их как `_fastcall`, то получится код

```
test    cl, cl
sete    al
```

(ср. с Open Watcom ниже).

Очень забавно повел себя Open Watcom (для него пришлось заменить `bool` на `int`):

```
f_:
L$1:
    test        eax,eax 
    sete        al 
    movzx       eax,al 
    ret         

g_:
    jmp         L$1
```

Он вообще перебросил вызов `g` в `f`! :)

Точно то же он сделал и в режиме С++ (оптимизации в обоих случаях - по умолчанию).

```
bool near f( bool ):
L$1:
    test        al,al 
    sete        al 
    ret         

bool near g( bool ):
    jmp         L$1
```

При полной оптимизации в режиме C он просто слил обе функции:

```
f_:
g_:
    test        eax,eax 
    sete        al 
    movzx       eax,al 
    ret
```

Comment: Не на Си, а на Си++. А без плюсов у тебя вместо bool окажется int и xor станет некорректным, т. к. из 2 надо получить 0, а не 3. Добавь для Си?

Comment: @Qwertiy Получилось, в общем-то, одно и то же...

Comment: @Qwertiy Рекомендую посмотреть, что делает Open Watcom - это просто песня: он из `g` делает `jmp` прямо в `f`. Уж тут 200%, что код одинаков! :)

Comment: А почему push выжил?

Comment: @Qwertiy А, он при вызове без ключиков вставляет проверку стека. Я ее убрал - она к делу не относится, а `push`'и забыл...

Comment: А зачем ему 2 функции с jmp'ом? Он имел право одну сделать, или это лучше отдельным вопросом спросить?

Comment: @Qwertiy  Ну, тут что вижу, то и пою :) - не я Open Watcom разрабатывал... Сейчас еще немного в раздел VC++ доложу.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618908/178988

Answer (score 1):

В случае с отрицанием должен быть создан такой набор ассемблерных команд:

- Загрузка в регистр из оперативной памяти.
- Операция инверсии.
- Сохранение в оперативную память

Причем 1 и 3 - не обязательно. Зависит от того, что идет дальше и что было раньше.

При сравнении (не обязательно именно так, тут и компилятор может оптимизировать и в зависимости от процессора может другой код получится):

- Загрузка в регистр
- Вычитание 1
- Проверка флага на знак и условный переход по нему
- Сохранение в оперативную память нового значения.

Как видите разница не очень большая. Вывод?

а) Предпочитайте понятный и красивый код вместо оптимизированного.

б) Сначала тестируйте приложение или вручную, или исходя из здравого смысла, или профилировщиком, а потом уже оптимизируйте узкие места.

Comment: Я пишу для микропроцессора - вот и возникла мысль, что второй вариант гораздо быстрее, просто я ассемблера не знаю.

Comment: Какой-то сомнительный список с набором команд. Это не команды. И операции инверсии не существует. Там же будет `test`, затем `jz`, не?

Comment: Я не претендую на супер точность, я предполагаю лишь, что команды будут такими. И почему это не существует? В некоторых процессорах есть команда Not

Answer (score 1):

Так называемая "оптимизация" этого фрагмента кода абсолютно никак не скажется на производительность вашей программы. А вот на читабельность и понимание вашей программы очень может сказаться.

Данный фрагмент кода

```
if (var1) var2 = false;
else var2 = true;
```

выглядит очень запутанно. Не сразу видно, что `var2` - это отрицание `var1`.

Чтобы было еще более наглядно видно, что этот код запутанный, представьте, что в этом месте надо выйти из функции. Тогда вам придется писать.

```
if (var1) var2 = false;
else var2 = true;
return var2;
```

Данный же фрагмент кода

```
var2 = !var1;
```

более ясный. Из него сразу же видно, что значением переменной `var2` является отрицание значения переменной `var1`. С дополнительным предложением `return` все может быть записано в одну строчку

```
return !var1;
```

Или если нужно, чтобы переменная `var2` обязательно получила значение, то

```
return  var2 = !var1;
```

Более того, например в C++ без всяких дополнительных включений, вы можете написать даже так

```
return not var1;
```

Или

```
return  var2 = not var1;
```

В C для этого достаточно будет включить заголовок `<iso646.h>`

Более того в том же C++ можно объявлять переменные в условиях. Поэтому если переменная используется только, например, в теле предложения if или в цикле, то можно написать

```
if ( bool var2 = not var1 )
{
    // using var2
}
```

или

```
while ( bool var2 = not var1 )
{
    //...
}
```

И даже в C, где нельзя объявлять переменные в условиях, тем не менее лучше записать

```
bool var2;

while ( var2 = !var1 )
{
   // changing of var1
}
```

Comment: Ну для микроконтроллеров может и сказаться. Причём, как в плане объёма кода, так и в плане скорости. Впрочем, если это так, то стоило сразу писать на ассемблере и не мучиться.