# Могут ли функции иметь один адрес?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer

В [ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618859/178988) говорится, что Open Watcom компилирует такой код

```
bool f(bool var1)
{
  bool var2 = !var1;
  return var2;
}

bool g(bool var1)
{
  bool var2;
  if (var1) var2 = 0;
  else var2 = 1;
  return var2;
}
```

следующим образом

```
bool near f( bool ):
L$1:
    test        al,al 
    sete        al 
    ret         

bool near g( bool ):
    jmp         L$1
```

Т. е. из функции `g` делается `jmp` в начало функции f.

Получается, что у функции `g` есть лишний `jmp` по сравнению с `f`.

- Зачем это нужно и почему нельзя было просто саму функцию `g` совместить с `f`?

  ```
  bool near f( bool ):
  bool near g( bool ):
      test        al,al 
      sete        al 
      ret
  ```
- Что на эту тему говорит стандарт? Например, есть ли там пункт, что указатели на две различные функции обязаны быть различными? Если есть, то что он даёт?
- Какие плюсы от такой реализации?

Comment: Оно? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26533740/276994

Comment: @VladD, похоже, да.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На основе дискуссии [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26533740/276994):

### Нет, адреса не должны быть равными

[Стандарт, 5.10/2.2-3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq#2.2), гласит:

> — Otherwise, if the pointers are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address ([basic.compound]), they compare equal.
>
> — Otherwise, the pointers compare unequal.

Компилятор **имеет право**, однако, сделать их равными по as-if rule, то есть, если это не влияет на видимый результат работы программы. Поэтому даже если конкретный компилятор совместил функции в отсутствие получения и сравнения их адресов, это ещё не нарушение стандарта. (Компилятор вообще имеет право выкинуть все функции, если этого никто не заметит.)

---

По поводу возможного *практического использования* этого правила. 
Пусть у нас есть контейнер функций (указателей на функции) — например, `std::unordered_set` — с условием уникальности. Если два независимых участка кода добавляют в него локально определённую, невидимую другим участкам кода функцию, они могут быть уверены, что функция имеет уникальный адрес и будет реально добавлена. В противном случае добавление локально определённой функции могло бы и не сработать, если в другом месте другой код добавил локальную функцию с таким же кодом.

Ещё один пример того, когда несклеивание функций полезно, из упомянутого обсуждения: [`SIG_IGN` и `SIG_DFL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/SIG_strategies) обязаны быть *различными* адресами. Имплементация стандартной библиотеки вполне может использовать пустые функции `void ign(int) { }` и `void dfl(int) { }`. «Склеивание» этих функций сломает код.

Comment: _"both point to the same function"_ - а это не подвох? Т. е. если разные функции обязаны иметь разные адреса, то этот кусок фразы можно просто выкинуть и смысл не изменится. Но тут они зачем-то упоминаются. Нет ли чего интересного в понимании "same function"?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну так это вроде бы и есть тот кусок, который *утверждает*, что разные функции должны иметь разные адреса.

Comment: Разные по месту в исходнике, или разные по содержимому?

Comment: Да, а где здесь про строки? Равенство строк ведь точно не гарантируется. Возможно, функции где-то рядом.

Comment: @Qwertiy: В стандарте вообще нет нигде равенства по одинаковому коду. Например, в ODR функции с разными именами считаются разными вне зависимости от того, одинаковая ли у них имплементация.

Comment: @Qwertiy: А какие строки?

Comment: `if ("abc" == "abc")` - такие.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну у меня в ответе ничего про строки нет же?

Comment: Аналогия: "строки с одинаковым содержимым могут быть равны или не равны по ссылке" vs "функции с одинаковым кодом могут быть равны или не равны по ссылке". Оба утверждения в равной мере подвергаются воздействию процитированного куска стандарта. Известно, что для первого случая ответ Да. Следовательно, нужен ещё какой-то кусок стандарта, чтобы эти случаи различать и для второго сказать Нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Этой аналогии нет. В стандарте говорится об объединении строковых **литералов** http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.string#16. Но литералы и не являются объектами.

Comment: _"SIG_IGN и SIG_DFL"_ - если обе штуки implemantation defined, то это ничего не значит. Как с нулевым адресом в `offsetof`. Кстати, этот кусок скорее против ответа, т. к. если у любых двух функций разные адреса, то нет необходимости дополнительно подчёркивать, что эти адреса ни с чем не совпадут.

Comment: @Qwertiy: Этот кусок — пример того, как можно *использовать* уникальность функций, а не подтверждение её.

Comment: Во, осталось убедиться, что для функций где-то нет такой фразы, как для строк :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Ну, опять-таки, для «функциональных литералов» тогда уже :)

Comment: "Но литералы и не являются объектами" - как и функции - это где-то на SO было в том ответе :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Пробежал соответствующий кусок стандарта: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def, ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 4):

Он делает это с оптимизацией **по умолчанию**. Вы поспешили с вопросом - я скомпилировал тот же код с максимальной оптимизацией, и он благополучно слил функции в одну (добавил в оригинальный ответ):

```
Module: G:\Tmp\test.c
GROUP: 'DGROUP' CONST,CONST2,_DATA

Segment: _TEXT PARA USE32 00000009 bytes
0000                          f_:
0000                          g_:
0000    85 C0                     test        eax,eax 
0002    0F 94 C0                  sete        al 
0005    0F B6 C0                  movzx       eax,al 
0008    C3                        ret         

Routine Size: 9 bytes,    Routine Base: _TEXT + 0000
```

Подозрение, что полная оптимизация - многопроходная, а по умолчанию - проход только один. Доказать не могу :), но такая гипотеза объясняет это поведение...

Comment: Всё же неясно, разрешена ли такая оптимизация стандартом.

Comment: @VladD, а почему нет?

Comment: @VladD Поскольку обе функции в одном исходном файле - думаю, вполне. Любое изменение в любой из них потребует перекомпиляции обеих.

Comment: @Grundy: Ну вот об этом как бы и вопрос.

Comment: @VladD, а если я напишу `if (f == g)`? А ещё лучше `if (x == f)`, а кто-то мне отдаёт равный указатель, но на другую функцию? Или это очередное UB? Как со строками `if (x == "abc")`

Comment: @Qwertiy: Понимаю, вот поэтому мне и интересно. Кстати, поскольку реально адрес функций никто не берёт, оптимизатор может заюзать as-if rule.

Comment: @Qwertiy Хреново. Я дописал `int h() { return (f == g); }`, но он ухитрился - при полной оптимизации! - все равно сделать `mov         eax,offset f_     cmp         eax,offset g_`. Впрочем, OW никогда не отличался следованием стандарту :(

Comment: Недооптимизировал он до `if (true)`, который потом бы вообще выкинул...

Comment: @Qwertiy Он не только недооптимизировал, но он по-хорошему должен был бы как раз `0` вернуть - ну, сделать вид, что функции-то разные :)