# как определить inline функцию?

Tags: c++, функции, inline

Как определить встроилась ли функция или у нее свой адрес и реализация, как у не встраимовой функции? Компилятор может игнорировать инструкцию, тем более если я запрашиваю адрес функции. А как определить непонятно, только в ассемблер-код смотреть?

```
#include <iostream>

void func () {
    std::cout << "func";
}

inline void func2() { func(); }


int main()
{
    std::cout << uint64_t(&func) << " || " << uint64_t(&func2) << std::endl;
    // Пример вывода: 4199872 || 4204384
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В GCC есть атрибут `__always_inline__`.

Comment: Вы уже ее определили. В чем тогда вопрос? И о каком языке идёт речь? В С и в С++ inline  работает совершенно по-разному.

Comment: Вопрос: как определить встроилась ли функция или у нее свой адрес и реализация, как у не встраимовой функции?

Comment: Посмотреть ассемблер. Если у нее есть адрес, то это не значит, что в других местах она не встраивается.

Comment: @VTT то есть одна и та же функция может где то встраиваться а где то вызываться? или что у встраиваемой функции может быть адрес, хотя везде по коду функция встраивается?

Comment: Да, функция может и встраиваться и вызываться

Comment: А зачем Вам это? Может и ненужно вовсе?

Comment: Адреса всегда разные: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618917/178988.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот так и определять. С помощью `inline`, понимая, что компилятор может ее встроить, может не встроить, а может встроить и без всякого `inline`...

В некоторых компиляторах есть расширения, которые заставляют компилятор прибегнуть ко встраиванию (например, [`__forceinline`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=vs-2019#inline-__inline-and-__forceinline) в Visual C++), но это уже нестандарт...

Comment: Даже эти инструкции не могут заставить компилятор встраивать. Это просто «сильно сильно попросить».

Comment: По ссылке пишут, что если `__forceinline` не заинлайнится, то будет предупреждение кроме двух случаев.